# SSRS function with regex

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report using SSRS for a phone number field in my database as a string value.  I need to format a string value in phone number format (555) 555-1212.  If the value is null, display nothing.

For example, a table in my database has a phone number column and some values are NULL.

I got a regex that formats the phone number fine.

> =System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!Phone.Value,
>   "(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{4})","($1) $2-$3")

However if I do this:

> =IIf(Fields!Phone.Value is nothing, "", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!Phone.Value,"(\d{3})[
>   -.]*(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{4})","($1) $2-$3"))

Then it comes back with an error.  #ERROR is displayed on my report.  Can you use iif with a regex?  Is there another way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you're only getting #ERROR for your null-valued records, since that's what happened when I set up a test case using the expression you provided. If not, I'll investigate further.)

You certainly can use a regex inside of the `IIF()` statement, but it [evaluates both result conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28VS.71%29.aspx) regardless of the result of your test expression. Therefore, your `Regex.replace()` is performed on your `NULL` values as well, which naturally generates an error.

I was able to produce the behaviour I think that you're after by rearranging things a little, so that we have this expression instead (formatted for readability):

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
  IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Phone.Value), "", Fields!Phone.Value),
  "(\d{3})[ -.](\d{3})[ -.](\d{4})",
  "($1) $2-$3")
```

That will give you a blank field when the value is `NULL`, otherwise it will format your telephone numbers accordingly. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I only needed to format the regex just a bit. =System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Phone.Value), "", Fields!Phone.Value), "(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3")